# how to convince edge labels to be above/below edge, when they are slanted?

Tags: tikz-pgf, edge

with the

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto]
\draw (0,0) to ["AA" '] + (2,0);
\draw (0,0) to ["BB"]   + (0,2);
%
\draw (3,0) to ["AA" ']      +(2,0);
\draw (3,0) to ["BB",sloped] +(0,2);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

i obtain

[image]

if i predefined edge quotes for example as

```
every edge quotes/.append style = {auto=left, font=\footnotesize\sffamily,
                                   anchor=south, sloped}
```

than `swap` or `'` option hasn't any influence to label positioning (some how expected, since anchor is fixed).

is there a way that in second image label be positioned above/left or below/right side of a line and be in the same time sensitive to option `swap` (or `'`)?

Comment: This problem only shows up when the label is exactly turned 90 degrees. `\draw (3,0) to ["BB",sloped] +(1,2);` for example has the desired result.

Comment: You shouldn't have a comma before `sloped`, but a space. It doesn't solve the problem, though.

Comment: @JasperHabicht I wonder if `auto` is well-defined here? That is, which way should it jump?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Almost, `\draw (3,0) to ["BB"sloped] +(0.10015107,2);` will  give a node next to the line. The position is still wrong though (wrong anchor), you can see that the node isn't placed `midway` on the line, something `["BB"{sloped,anchor=south}]` will fix.  Seems `auto` simply doesn't take the rotation by `sloped` into account.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., from your comment i conclude, that this is missed feature in `tikz` or its bug. your solution i can use as temporary solution (do you intend to write an answer?) and then wait in hope, that some new `tikz` version will fix this.

Comment: You already had basically the same solution in your question, so that wasn't really anything new ... You shouldn't just hope though, you should report the problem at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs/?source=navbar

Comment: @TorbjørnT., with this i have problems ... i must confess that report my problem is over my abilty (i'm lost in this) :-(

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/feature-requests/111/

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is what you expect.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\def\tikz@install@auto@anchor@sloped{\let\tikz@do@auto@anchor=\tikz@auto@anchor@on\def\tikz@auto@anchor@direction{sloped}}
\def\tikz@install@auto@anchor@sroped{\let\tikz@do@auto@anchor=\tikz@auto@anchor@on\def\tikz@auto@anchor@direction{sroped}}
\def\tikz@auto@anchor@sloped{\pgfslopedattimetrue\tikz@auto@pre\tikz@auto@anchor@sloped@\tikz@auto@post}
\def\tikz@auto@anchor@sroped{\pgfslopedattimetrue\tikz@auto@pre\tikz@auto@anchor@sroped@\tikz@auto@post}
\def\tikz@auto@anchor@sloped@{%
    \ifdim\pgf@x<0pt%
        \def\tikz@anchor{north}%
    \else%
        \def\tikz@anchor{south}%
    \fi%
}
\def\tikz@auto@anchor@sroped@{%
    \ifdim\pgf@x<0pt%
        \def\tikz@anchor{south}%
    \else%
        \def\tikz@anchor{north}%
    \fi%
}
\tikzoption{swap}[]{%
    \def\tikz@swap@left@to{right}%
    \def\tikz@swap@right@to{left}%
    \def\tikz@swap@sloped@to{sroped}%
    \def\tikz@swap@sroped@to{sloped}%
    \edef\tikz@auto@anchor@direction{\csname tikz@swap@\tikz@auto@anchor@direction @to\endcsname}
}

\tikz\draw foreach\i in{3,6,...,36}{(0,0)--node[auto=sloped]{ABC}+(\i0:3)};

\tikz\draw foreach\i in{3,6,...,36}{(0,0)--node[auto=sloped,']{ABC}+(\i0:3)};

\tikz\draw foreach\i in{3,6,...,36}{(0,0)--node[auto=sroped]{ABC}+(\i0:3)}; % sroped = sloped'

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: thank you very much. it is close (+1), but not exactly what i looking for (positioning edge quotes).

Comment: @Zarko It should apply to edge quotes without accident. I tried `\tikz\draw foreach\i in{3,6,...,36}{(0,0)to["ABC",auto=sloped]+(\i0:3)};` and it works.